# why jsessionid is not generating in my jsp source code?

Tags: jsp, spring-security, http-status-code-404, jsessionid

I'm trying with Spring security login, below is the login.jsp, when I run the same jsp in two different applications, one application is not generating **jsessionid**, resulting 404 error, the other application is generating jsessionid and working fine. could you please help me with this issue.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>

</head>
<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>

    <h1>Spring Security Custom Login Form (XML)</h1>

    <div id="login-box">

        <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>

        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="error">${error}</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>

        <form name='loginForm'
            action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>" method='POST'>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                        value="submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                value="${_csrf.token}" />

        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>IAuthor</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>IAuthor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/IAuthor-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>IAuthor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: could you show me your `web.xml`

Comment: I have updated with web.xml

Comment: *"one application is not generating jsessionid, resulting 404 error"* this conclusion doesn't make any sense. I guess you just misobserved/misinterpreted the real problem. Please describe exactly what is happening and what exactly not. Also, "generating jsessionid" is rather vague and ambiguous. Please use proper terminology. If you're unable to, then please clarify the concrete business/functional requirements.